# parent-child relation to flat view

Tags: sql, parent-child

Is there an easy way to migrate a table with a parent child relation to a column one ?

INPUT_TABLE

```
PARENT_ID,ID,NAME
null,1, USA
1   ,2, Las Vegas
2   ,3, City in las Vegas
2   ,4, Another City in las Vegas
.. a lot more
```

OUTPUT

```
ID, COUNTRY, CITY, PLACE
1,  USA, null,null
2,  USA, Las Vegas,null
3,  USA, Las Vegas,City in las Vegas
4,  USA, Las Vegas,Another City in las Vegas
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about making XML structure for that data?

Comment: How deep is your recursion?  If you have a set limit, this becomes much easier.  You haven't specified the RDBMS - that could be extremely important in the answers given out.  Also, is there a specific reason you have rows 1 and 2, instead of just row 3?

Comment: Ideally the algo would be generic, but let's take 3. Don't sure to understand your last question, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: I got it, you can have several cities in USA and several places in a city.. you're right for this example the first two rows are useless

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have a hierarchie of 3 items as per your comments and there's no need to retain rows that have no `City` or `Place`, joining the table twice with itself would suffice.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  ID = Country.ID
        , Country = Country.NAME
        , City = City.NAME
        , Place = Place.Name
FROM    q Country
        INNER JOIN q City ON City.PARENT_ID = Country.ID
        INNER JOIN q Place ON Place.PARENT_ID = City.ID
```

#### (SQL Server) Test script

```
;WITH q (PARENT_ID, ID, NAME) AS (
  SELECT null, 1, 'USA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 'Las Vegas'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 'City in las Vegas'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4, 'Another City in las Vegas'
)
SELECT  ID = Country.ID
        , Country = Country.NAME
        , City = City.NAME
        , Place = Place.Name
FROM    q Country
        INNER JOIN q City ON City.PARENT_ID = Country.ID
        INNER JOIN q Place ON Place.PARENT_ID = City.ID
```